# Почему в одних бессоюзных сложных предложениях со значением следствия мы ставим тире, а в других — запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему, когда мы общаемся с "друзьями" в соцсетях и нам встречаются БСП с следственно-причинными частями, мы ставим тире только если нам попадаются конструкции типа:

> На улице гололёд — ни пройти, ни проехать.
> Тут функций всяких —закачаешься.

В остальных случаях (например, если оба простых предложения в составе бессоюзных сложных двусоставные и полные) мы машинально ставим запятую.

Answer (score 1):

Если при бессоюзной связи частей сложного предложения сначала идет следствие, а потом причина, то ставится двоеточие; если сначала идет причина, а потом следствие, то ставится тире. Больше тут добавить нечего. Вот несколько примеров:
Выйти невозможно: на улице проливной дождь.
На улице проливной дождь — выйти невозможно

Молодёжь ушла — на вечере стало скучно.
На вечере стало скучно: молодёжь ушла.

Answer (score 0):

Если опускается союз и наречие, то ставится тире, так как слишком многое опускается и сложно восстановить по смыслу:

```
На улице гололед сильный, что ни пройти, ни проехать.
Тут функций всяких много, что закачаешься.
```

Если опускается просто союз, то ставится запятая, так как союз легко восстанавливается по смыслу:

```
На улице гололед сильный, ни пройти, ни проехать.
Тут функций всяких много, закачаешься.
```